# Why doesn't my Manifest file declare a java package?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I can't seem to find an answer to this, so I guess I'll ask it myself. No matter what I try, Eclipse claims that my AndroidManifest.xml file doesn't declare a java package. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="hess.jacob.spindoctor"
    android:versionCode="19"
    android:versionName="4.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="hess.jacob.spindoctor.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Maybe someone can find the problem, and suggest a solution. I'd gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hess.jacob.spindoctor"
    android:versionCode="19"
    android:versionName="4.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="hess.jacob.spindoctor.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Package name is missing

You have set the name , not the package.

```
android:name="hess.jacob.spindoctor"
```

It should be

```
package="hess.jacob.spindoctor"
```